# Send value from one action to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have vendors/show view with button "Add new item" button. When i press "Add new item", it leads to items/new view with select which contain all Vendors.

I want to send vendor id value to items/new, that way it will be possible to show correct Vendor on my select.

How it can be done RIGHT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use nested [resources](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Resources/resources):

```
map.resources :vendors do |vendor|
  vendor.resources :items
end
```

Use `new_vendor_item_path(vendor)` in vendors/show for "Add new item"

And in your item `new` action:

```
@vendor = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
```